# Read Only Property On View Model in Spring MVC View

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

How do you access a read only property on a view model in Spring MVC view?

```
<img id="avatar" src="<c:url value="${model.getSquareImage}" />" />
```

---

```
public ImageModel getSquareImage() {

        if(getImages() != null && getImages().size() > 0)
            return getImages().get(0);

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `${model.squareImage}`, not `${model.getSquareImage}`. This is standard JSP/JavaBean stuff, and nothing to do with Spring or read-only properties.